# jQuery Dialog model and links

Tags: jquery

I want to show a dialog.

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "OK":function() { alert(" hi I m OK") },
                "Cancel Registration": function() { 
                    //$(this).dialog("close");

            }
        }
        });
```

Here I have set `modal:true` but I can't see any transparent or something around the dialog. How can I add a css or design it as I wish(example: add a color:light blue to the modal)

My other problem is , how to add a css or design the links  which are to 'close' in the dialog.(Not the body of the dialog)

Answer (score 2):

For theming use [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) to customize your jQueryUI theme.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed use the [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) or

Check what kind of style is applied (using an inspector) and overwrite the css (when it isn't supposed to be for the entire webapp/site).

in this case: ui-widget-overlay [image: chrome inspect element example]